# How to show javascript (html?) graph in hudson

Tags: javascript, html, jenkins, hudson, hudson-plugins

I have a piece of Javascript (html page??) that displays a graph of some data. The piece of code looks like:

```
<html>
<head>

    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="stringformat.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

           ... script...

    </script>
</head>

<body>
<!--Div that will hold the line graph-->
    <div id="chart_div_netLatency"></div>
    <div id="chart_div_mamaLatency"></div>
    <div id="chart_div_fhLatency"></div>
    <div id="chart_div_totalLatency"></div>

    <input id="date-input" style=margin-left:160px type="text"  id="date" name="date" />
    <input type="button" value="submit" onClick="updateData();"/>
    <p style=margin-left:160px> Date format: YYYY.MM.DD </p>

    <img  style=margin-left:30px src="timeline.bmp" alt="timeline"/>

</body>
```

Could anyone tell me if there's a way to show the graph produced by this script in Hudson.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a link to the script in the sidebar using [this plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Sidebar-Link+Plugin) or do it more dynamically by giving the links in a text file with [this plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/AnchorChain+plugin).

Comment: Is it possible to just put that html/javascript page into hudson without redirecting it to some other places? Cause I didn't want to make another host for that html page

Comment: You can put anything you want into that link, including a relative link to a page within Hudson/Jenkins.

Comment: I tried to use the sidebar link plugin to link to an html page  /HUDSONHOME/jobs/some-plot/report.html and the hudson returned with a status code 404. Could you tell me what happened there?

Comment: The easiest way to do this would be to go to the page you want to link to in the Hudson workspace (or artifact) and then copy and paste that URL.